# TPaintBox does not paint on TButton event "onClick"

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I have simple FreePascal code with TButton and TPaintBox.

I have events on these elements:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     Button1.Enabled := False;
     Button2.Enabled := True;
     Button1.Caption := 'Off';
     Button2.Caption := 'On';
     PaintBox1.Invalidate;
     PaintBox1.Color := clYellow;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
   PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
   PaintBox1.Canvas.Ellipse(0,0,100,50);
end;
```

But it does not paint my TPaintBox with onClick event on TButton.

Can anybody help me, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `TPaintBox.Color` color is mistakenly published property. It doesn't fill the background or do anything (at least in Delphi, in Lazarus it will be the same, I'd say).

Also, you should have call `Invalidate` after you set that color, but if it does nothing, you don't need to care about it now. You can write it this way instead:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // the TPaintBox.Color does nothing, so let's use it for passing the
  // background color we will fill later on in the OnPaint event
  PaintBox1.Color := clYellow;
  // and tell the system we want to repaint our paint box
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // set the brush color to the TPaintBox.Color
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := PaintBox1.Color;
  // and fill the background by yourself
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(PaintBox1.ClientRect);
  // and then draw an ellipse
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Ellipse(0, 0, 100, 50);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot. It works. I am beginner with FreePascal (Lazarus) and there are no good tutorials about it.